# Grafana tempo: What is multitenancy?

Tags: grafana-tempo

I am going through grafana tempo documentation, and I came across [multi-tenancy](https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/operations/multitenancy/).

Also, there is a github [example](https://github.com/grafana/tempo/tree/main/example/docker-compose/otel-collector-multitenant) for it.

But I dont really understand it as a whole. What are we trying to achieve here? And how to see the impact on trace search results?

A very simple example would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Multitenancy in Grafana basically provides you with the ability to host "isolated" instances (called tenants) so that there can be different, independent environments for different orgs or teams. This is usually useful for use cases where you want to have multiple teams on one Grafana platform while also maintaining data separation and security.

Comment: So if there are multiple teams having their services running, and we have a tempo trace which passes through all these services, then multi-tenancy allows to get information of all those individual services. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure about this - usually I would assume that you would not be able to get information about the individual services if they are in separate tenants